# Python, get method for dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, get

I try to use `get` method of dictionaries to avoid an `if-else` structure, but the method returns a `None` object, whereas I want a list. My code :

```
dic = {}
words = ['foo', 'bar']
for word in words :
    long = len(word)
    dic[long] = dic.get(long, []).append(word)
```

I want to have (at the end of the loop) :

```
{3:['foo', 'bar']}
```

But I have :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Which means that `get` returned a `None` object (default value)... where I though it should return a void list if the key doesn't exists, a list filled withs some strings if the key exists. Any ideas ?

Comment: You'll probably have an easier time if you just use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score -1):

```
dic = {}
words = ['foo', 'bar']
for word in words :
    long = len(word)
    if (dic.has_key(long)):
        dic[long].append(word)
    else:
        dic[long] = [word]
```